# How does the Bing traffic API bounding box work?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I am using the Bing traffic API for getting the traffic info in a particular region.

As you might be aware this uses the Bounding box for providing data.

I have read quite a lot about Bounding box but was not able to understand it completely(sorry for that.)

Some how I found the code that provides the bounding box accepting coordinates and the distance.
I have used the coordinates as : 42.991169,-71.463089 and distance as 10 km. 
The bounding box that I am getting is having following coordinates:

```
43.036154579568404,-71.40158782044901  |   42.946183420431595,-71.52459017955098
```

First of all since I was not able to understand completely, I don't even know if these are being calculated correctly.

Secondly, when I call the API using these parameters I get : "This parameter value is out of range".
The url shall be: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/43.036154579568404,-71.40158782044901,42.946183420431595,-71.52459017955098?key=Ag9nBodFBoKycjBSvcv_-INwIkVMm4kMeyz_BfMFeOTqi1uV3nPr_ku5UpebHF7t

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates are in the wrong order. Try this: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/42.946183420431595,-71.52459017955098,43.036154579568404,-71.40158782044901?key=YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY

The bounding box format is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701726.aspx